# Scroll background image of webpage with content

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a webpage with a static CSS background, but the content is longer than the height of the image. This causes whitespace at the bottom after the image ends.

How can I make the image scroll along with the view of the user's screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

See http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/demo.html for a more detailed example.